# Using Backbone.Collection fetch but value not including

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I thought that initializing the collection returned a ready instance of Backbone.Collection. After the fetch, however, the collection contains some models, but in require, _this.serviceCollection.toJSON() gives me undefined object.

My Backbone.Collection:

```
var ServiceCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Backbone.Model,
    initialize: function(options){
        this.fetch({
            url: 'service/' + options + '/',
            async: false,
            success: function(collection, response, options){
                collection.set(response.result);
            }
        });
    }
});

return ServiceCollection;
```

My CollectionView showing:

```
    OpenServices: function(category){
        var _this = this;
        require([
            'service/js/service_collection',
            'service/js/service_collection_view'
        ], function(ServiceCollection, ServiceCollectionView){
            _this.serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection(category);
            _this.serviceCollectionView = new ServiceCollectionView({
                collection: _this.serviceCollection
            });
            _this.categoryLayout.categoryItems.show(_this.serviceCollectionView);
        });
    }
```

What's wrong this code?

Comment: What is the value of category..?Are you aware that fetch is asynchronous..?  Where did you add `_this.serviceCollection.toJSON()`..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistake was in sync/async request. My fetch was async: false, so I'm just change it to async: true and a set event on reset collection for that collectionView.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue you are having is related to your `success` callback.  There should be no need to call `collection.set(...)` to add the models to the collection; that is done *automatically* for you when the `fetch` succeed.  In fact, [the documentation around Collection.set](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-set) provides this nugget:

> ...  if the collection contains any models that aren't present in the list, they'll be removed.

I suspect that `response.result` in your success callback doesn't contain any of the data you think it does.  Because of that, your call to `collection.set(...)` is actually removing all items from the collection.

Try removing that `success` callback & see what else happens.

---

Somewhat unrelated but still important:

- Using `Collection.fetch(...)` synchronously is considered bad practice; if your server takes longer than a few hundred milliseconds to return the data, the browser may lock up.
- Specifying the `url` as a parameter to `Collection.fetch(...)` is not a terrible idea, but consider extending `Backbone.Model` and specifying the `urlRoot` parameter instead.  If your server follows REST-ful conventions, it makes it very easy to create/update/delete data that way.